# Sufficient condition for Radon measure be Haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

I am reading Dinakar Ramakrishnan&Robert J.Valenza *Fourier Analysis on  Number Fields*.

I want to understand following proposition.

> Prop 1-7 (ii)
>   Let $G$ be a locally compact group with nonzero Radon measure $\mu $.
>
> The measure $\mu$ is a left Haar measure on G if and only if 
>   $$
> \int_{G} L_s f d\mu = \int _G f d\mu
> $$
>   for all $f \in \mathcal{C}_c^{+}$ and $s \in G$

And following is the proof of this prop.

> Convrsely, from the positive linear functional $\int_G \cdot d\mu$ on $\mathcal{C_c}(G)$ we can, by the Riesz representation theorem, explicitly  recover the Radon measure $\mu$ of any open subset $U \subset G$ as follows:
>   $$
> \mu (U) = sup \{\int_G f d\mu \mid f \in \mathcal{C_c}(G), \ \|f\|_u \leq 1, \ and \ supp(f) \subset U \}
> $$

I am wondering why the last equality holds.

Thank you for your directions.

Comment: Notice how $Fourier Analysis \ on \ Number Fields$ has weird spacing?  It is better to do it with stars instead of dollar-signs: *Fourier Analysis on Number Fields*.

Comment: The title and actual body text seem at odds to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be  compact subset of $U$. Since $G$ is locally compact there exists $f \in C_c(G)$ such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$, $f=1$ on $K$ with support inside $U$. Note that $\mu (K) \leq \int f d\mu$ which does not exceed the RHS. Since $\mu$ is Radon we can take supremum over all $K$ to get LHS $\leq$ RHS. The reverse inequality is obvious.